# Как запустить консоль на Ubuntu для установки демона

Tags: php, ubuntu, консоль

Всем привет! 
Сейчас начинаю разбираться с WebSocket и необходимо установить phpDaemon на Denwer.

[Вот мануал](https://github.com/kakserpom/phpdaemon/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-(%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5)) по установке но есть пункты, которые мне пока не понятны(

1. Где в денвере размещается папка исходников php?
2. Как запустить консоль для выполнения команд, скажем:

   ```
   /usr/bin/php --version
   ```

или

```
    chmod +x go.sh
    make && make install
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @qulery denwer + ubuntu ?  
вы ничего не путаете?  
Этот мануал для линуксов.

Comment: Хм... А как мне быть, если я в качестве виртуального сервера использую Denwer? Возможна ли установка демона на него?

Answer (score 1):

[[@qulery](/users/12603/qulery)](/users/12603/qulery) первая мысля: выдать гневную тераду.
Сходил покурил и теперь спокойненько:

1. Денвер не виртуальный сервер, а набор утилит в который входит вполне натуральный сервер и при должной настройки может использоваться в боевых условиях (оно вам надо?)
2. `phpDaemon` написан на `php` (кто бы мог подумать), из чего следует, что для его работы вам в первую очередь нужен интерпритатор `php`, который входит в `denwer` (а ещё `libevent` которую я хз как поставить в масдае. Гугл в помощь)
3. Мой вам совет: освойте работу в линуксе. Это вам очень пригодится. Толковых книг море(сам учился по [Linux. От новичка к профессионалу](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/18060927/)))

P.s. В размер коммента не влез

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Простите меня за мою глупость)
Я так понимаю в Денвере есть интерпритатор php. Соответственно phpDaemon будет работать на нем?

Comment: @qulery хз. Автор пишет про [libevent][1]. Что-то мне подсказывает, что вы врядли справитесь с его компиляцией на винде.
вот ещё [ссылка на гитхаб][2]


  [1]: http://libevent.org/
  [2]: https://github.com/libevent/libevent

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй сделать как сделал я. Установи Ubuntu server на виртуальную машину, VirtualBox, например. Настрой её как положено и там уже запускай своего демона для сокета. Вот ссылка с полной подробной инструкциеё установки и настройки. Все будет работать по принципу Денвера. Ну и гугл в помочь.
http://xn--d1acnqm.xn--j1amh/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8/web_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_1_%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0_virtualbox